# Using sentinel-controlled loop

Tags: java, while-loop, sentinel

I'm having trouble with an exercise asking to have a user prompt a name and echoes that name to the screen until user enters a sentinel value. I understand this is a sentinel-controlled loop but I'm stuck on the fact that I'm dealing with entering a name instead of an integer. I tried to follow a program in my book which only explains how to use a sentinel value with integers but not with String "name". I tried looking up this answer and saw something like name.equals("stop") if it even applies to this. and looked it up on the APIs and still didn't find it helpful. I would like to see how it applies as a whole.
Note: here is what I have done so far and I want to know how far off I am.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SentinelControlledLoop {

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    static final int SENTINEL = #;

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        String name;
        System.out.println("Enter a name " + "ending with " + SENTINEL); 
        String name = reader.next();

        while (!name.equals(“stop”)) {
            name = reader.next();
        }
```

Comment: Show us the code that you tried?

Comment: there i added what i have so far..

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
    name = reader.next();
} while (name.lastIndexOf(SENTINEL) == -1);
```

I assume that name cannot contain the sentinel in it. In other case, change `== -1` to

```
!= length(name) - 1
```

PS. You're declaring `String name` twice.

PS2. Even better condition:

```
while (!name.endsWith(String.valueOf(SENTINEL));
```

Comment: does it matter if the sentinel value is a name or could it be something like # like what i have

Comment: yes thank you very much i know my code is a mess im new to this :)

Comment: The sentinel value is not a name, it's a `#` as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

**The use of sentinel for loop:**

> In a sentinel controlled loop the change part depends on data from the user. It is awkward to do this inside a for statement. So the change part is omitted from the for statement and put in a convenient location.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class EvalSqrt
{
  public static void main (String[] args )
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
    double x;

    System.out.print("Enter a value for x or -1 to exit: ")  ;
    x = scan.nextDouble();

    for (    ; x >= 0.0 ;   )  
    {
      System.out.println( "Square root of " + x + " is " + Math.sqrt( x ) ); 

      System.out.print("Enter a value for x or -1 to exit: ")  ;
      x =  scan.nextDouble();
    }
  }
}
```

For more details: https://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap41/ch41_13.html

Answer (score 0):

> an exercise asking to have a user prompt a name and echoes that name
> to the screen until user enters a sentinel value.

I would expect to see something more like:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String SENTINEL = "stop";
    String name;
    do { 
      System.out.print("Enter a name ('" + SENTINEL + "' to quit): "); 
      name = reader.nextLine();
      if (!name.equals(SENTINEL)) {
        System.out.println(name);
      }
    } while (!name.equals(SENTINEL));
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
  }
```